# Python merge two columns based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe with two columns 'Department' and 'Project'.

```
data = [['Sales', '', 1000], ['R&D', 'Alpha', 2000], ['Purchase', 'DE', 1500],['Communication', '', 2000], ['HR', '', 10020]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Department', 'Project', 'Amount'])
print(df)

   Department Project  Amount
0          Sales            1000
1            R&D   Alpha    2000
2       Purchase      DE    1500
3  Communication            2000
4             HR           10020
```

I want to replace the Department entry by the Project entry if the Project entry is not empty. So the dataframe looks like that:

```
   Department Project  Amount
0          Sales            1000
1          Alpha   Alpha    2000
2             DE      DE    1500
3  Communication            2000
4             HR           10020
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `pandas.DataFrame.where`:

```
df["Department"] = df["Project"].where(df["Project"].ne(''), df["Department"])

>>> df
      Department Project  Amount
0          Sales            1000
1          Alpha   Alpha    2000
2             DE      DE    1500
3  Communication            2000
4             HR           10020
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `np.where()`. Kindly try:

```
df['Department'] = np.where(df['Project'].replace('',np.nan).isna(),df['Department'],df['Project'])
```

This outputs:

```
      Department Project  Amount
0          Sales            1000
1          Alpha   Alpha    2000
2             DE      DE    1500
3  Communication            2000
4             HR           10020
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with `series.fillna` on column `Project` with column `Department`

```
df['Department'] = df['Project'].replace('',np.nan).fillna(df['Department'])
```

---

```
print(df)

      Department Project  Amount
0          Sales            1000
1          Alpha   Alpha    2000
2             DE      DE    1500
3  Communication            2000
4             HR           10020
```